# A Generalised Bijection from Tuples of Natural Numbers to Natural Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

I've used the tag "set-theory" in lieu of "bijections".

When we represent (as is done by the OEIS) an infinite two dimensional sequence by the concatenation of antidiagonals, the *index* of an entry in that sequence is given by a bijection between ℕ×ℕ & ℕ. (ℕ may be ℕ₀ or ℕ₁ - it doesn't affect the essential argument - it's just a matter of *offsets* ... but I'll stick to casting all this in terms of ℕ₀, as then the formulæ are the simplest.) Explicitly the bijection is $$q=$$$$\frac{(m+n)(m+n+1)}{2}+n$$$$=$$$$\frac{(m+n)^{\overline{2}}}{2!}+n$$$$=$$$$\frac{(m+n)^2+m+3n}{2} ,$$ with the notation in the *middle* formula being the *ascending pochhammer* notation ... the reason I have bothered to broach this notation here shall be made clear shortly. I once saw the third  formula given in it's own right as the simplest possible bijection from duples of natural numbers to natural numbers; and it is sufficient in its own right to serve as a bijection between tuples of naturals of *any* given order & the naturals - by applying it recursively. (Please mark, though, this does **not** mean between *all tuples* & singletons - it means *between all tuples **of some one given order*** & singletons!)

But if we are to *actually do* such a mapping, there might be a 'tidier' (& more *disciplined* ) way of doing it ... forall its being so very 'handy' a formula, that third one. I'm *fairly* sure this works ... and the question is, can anyone tell me from their experience or knowledge that it *does* work? ... I'm not of course asking anyone to do the derivation *for* me. As far as I can tell it *does* ... but I *do* sometimes miss things, and I have not been able to find an exposition that says either *yea* or *nay* to it ... and it's this: if you have a tuple ${n_1, ... , n_r}$ would the most economical mapping - which *seems* to me to be the extension of the logic of the 2-dimensional case to arbitrary number $r$ of dimensions - be $$q=\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^k n_j\bigg)^\overline{k}}{k!}$$?

The logic is - and I'll merely expound it in a fairly *qualitative* fashion here so as not very greatly to prolong this post - that $$\frac{\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^k n_j\bigg)^\overline{k}}{k!} ,$$ being a *sum from to of a sum from to* ...  ($k$ instances thereof (if the termination be *sum from to **1***) ... triangular numbers, tetrahedral numbers, etc), creates the *minimum offset* necessary, at each item of the tuple, to ensure that the mapping does not become a *surjection*.

Actually, using that 'handy' formula recursively would not give rise to any *diseconomy* if the number of items in the tuple were a power of two, and the recursion applied to the tuple *treewise*. If you simply apply it to the general tuple at each element consecutively, you would be handling numbers of order of magnitude $$(\sum n)^{2^r} ,$$ such unnecessarily high orders of size corresponding to the implied *intermediate* tuples having a highly uneven distribution of value amongst their items.